# $http call cancelled automatically in Android when signed with Keystore

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, apk

Am developing a Hybrid app for Android platform. Everything was working fine till for both release and debug so far. Recently am getting into trouble where app $http calls is getting cancelled automatically.

And this is happening only if the APK is signed using the Keystore.
Have anyone faced this issue before ? Signed APK $http calls failing automatically :(

Note: Keystore is still valid.

Comment: Are you using https ? Please check your certificate.

Comment: No issues with Certificate. It is working fine